# Fatal signal: Segmentation fault in gdb, when value of vertain address is checked after loading a symbol file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb

My environment:

- `Linux My-PC 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- `Distributor ID: Ubuntu`
- `Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`

GDB-multiarch version

```
$ gdb-multiarch -v
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
```

Selected part of Makefile (Many things are ignored):

```
AS  =arm-linux-gnueabihf-as
LD  =arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld
NM  =arm-linux-gnueabihf-nm
LDFLAGS =-Timx6ul.lds 
CC  =arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc  $(RAMDISK)
CFLAGS  =-Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -nostdlib -fno-stack-protector -g

CPP =arm-linux-gnueabihf-cpp -nostdinc -Iinclude -lgcc -L/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11 -g

.c.s:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) \
    -nostdinc -Iinclude -S -o $*.s $<
.s.o:
    $(AS)  -o $*.o $<
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) \
    -nostdinc -Iinclude -c -o $*.o $<

all:    Image

Image: boot/start tools/system
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy -O binary -R .note -R .comment tools/system Image
    sync

tools/system:    init/main.o boot/start.o \
    $(ARCHIVES) $(DRIVERS) $(MATH) $(LIBS) 
    mkdir -p tools
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) init/main.o boot/start.o \
    $(ARCHIVES) \
    $(DRIVERS) \
    $(MATH) \
    $(LIBS) \
    -o tools/system -lgcc -L /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11 
    $(NM) -n tools/system > System.map

boot/start:boot/start.S
    $(AS) -o boot/start.o boot/start.S

qemu: all
    qemu-system-arm \
        -machine virt,gic-version=3 \
        -m 4G \
        -cpu cortex-a7 \
        -nographic \
        -device loader,file=Image,addr=0xC0008000,cpu-num=0 \
        -s -S 
        # -serial null -serial mon:stdio \
```

init.gdb:

```
target remote localhost:1234
set architecture arm
symbol-file tools/system
x/i 0xc0010f68
```

The problem is, when I check value at some certain address in gdb terminal, this error occurs. For thousands of instructions, gdb works as what I expect, but I'm so confused that why a segmentation fault occurs when value of certain address is fetched. In this case, I try to fetch instructions at `0xc0010f64` and `0xc0010f6c`, which turns out to be no problem.

```
Fatal signal: Segmentation fault
----- Backtrace -----
0x55e79b1e4197 ???
0x55e79b2e6599 ???
0x55e79b2e6762 ???
0x7f66f400951f ???
        ./signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/libc_sigaction.c:0
0x55e79b64560c ???
0x55e79b6452c5 ???
0x55e79b646831 ???
0x55e79b6469c9 ???
0x55e79b2761b1 ???
0x55e79b27718b ???
0x55e79b4437d7 ???
0x55e79b447f4b ???
0x55e79b448a0c ???
0x55e79b219774 ???
0x55e79b5a9d94 ???
0x55e79b2e76e4 ???
0x55e79b5ab99e ???
0x55e79b228443 ???
0x55e79b2163b7 ???
0x55e79b3b1da5 ???
0x55e79b3b1e39 ???
0x55e79b3b38d3 ???
0x55e79b3b43fe ???
0x55e79b10e0ef ???
0x7f66f3ff0d8f __libc_start_call_main
        ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
0x7f66f3ff0e3f __libc_start_main_impl
        ../csu/libc-start.c:392
0x55e79b113e24 ???
0xffffffffffffffff ???
---------------------
A fatal error internal to GDB has been detected, further
debugging is not possible.  GDB will now terminate.
```

I also found out that this happens only if `symbol-file tools/system` executes. If symbols are not loaded in gdb, gdb works well, so I wonder what's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be problems in the disassembler in gdb. `x/x 0xc0010f68` is ok and the result is `90 03 b0 84` which is `ldrthi r0, [r0], #0x390`, but if I type `x/i 0xc0010f68`, gdb will crash. The same thing happens when I use `layout asm` if asm window contains the instruction at ` 0xc0010f68`

Answer (score 0):

> so I wonder what's happening?

Obviously there is a bug in GDB.

But for anything more definitive than that you'll need to either make a reproducible test case, or at least use non-stripped version of `gdb-multiarch`, so the crashing function within it can be identified.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by avoiding `-fstrength-reduce`. I guess some of the instructions compiled by this option can not be identified in gdb?